# Using depth values for fake ambient occlusion

Tags: shaders, opengl-es, ssao

I'm using the normalized distance to the camera to get depth information in the fragment shader. When using this value as fragment color, it looks at lot like ambient occlusion (of course only in the right angle). I want to abuse this method to use it as fast AO approximation for my mobile game, but I don't know how to go on from here. My idea was to substract the distance of each fragment with a value from the projection to only leave the dark areas and remove the depth gradient. How would I procceed with this approach and is it even capable of achieving my desired result?

[image]